# Date in R - how to built it

Tags: r, datetime

I want to built in R a Date as:

02-06-year and 01-05-year

for 15 years, as I did for the other days (pasqua for example) as u can see in the next one:

```
listHolidays
seq=0:5000
data.iniziale <- as.Date("2015-01-01")
calendario=data.iniziale + seq
l=length(calendario)

for (i in 1:l){

pasqua[i]=holiday(year(calendario[i]),"Easter")

}
```

How can I do for that two date?

Thanks,
Raffaele

Comment: This question has a good start but is not reproducible. First, I'm inferring that you are using the `timeDate` package, please be explicit about that in questions on SO. Second, regardless of not knowing anything about `pasqua`, we really need to know what is wrong with the current code, and what your expected output is (a literal R object, if possible). Thanks.

Comment: Here the code:istHolidays
seq=0:5000
data.iniziale <- as.Date("2015-01-01")
calendario=data.iniziale + seq
l=length(calendario)

for (i in 1:l){

pasqua[i]=(year(calendario[i]),06,02)

}

Comment: how can I have this date? Thanks

Comment: First, no substantial code in comments please, the formatting is too limited. Second, that code is identical to what is in the question and does not answer the questions of: **what is `pasqua`?** and **what is your expected output?** For expected output, I'm looking for a ***literal R object***, such as `list(a=1,b=2)` or `data.frame(a=3:5)`.